# Querying Database with wpdb

Tags: php, post-meta, wpdb

I am trying to access a single value from my database through my `functions.php`. I have tried three different ways to get a result using a dynamic ID and none have worked. I always get NULL as the response. Using a WP_query is not possibility here, so I need to solve this using SQL.

**Attempt #1:**

```
global $post;
global $wpdb;
$post_ID = $post->ID;

$result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( 
"
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
    WHERE post_id = %d
    AND meta_key = 'wpcf-release-date' 
", 
$post_ID
) );
```

**Attempt #2:**

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'wpcf-release-date' AND post_id = $post_ID");
```

**Attempt #3:**

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'wpcf-release-date' AND post_id = " . $post_ID);
```

I know my query works, I tested the SQL query in Phpmyadmin with a static ID. I can also set the ID manually in my function which will yield a result, but does not help me if it is not dynamic.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT  `meta_value` 
FROM  `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE post_id = 249
AND meta_key =  'wpcf-release-date'
```

I assume I am overlooking something simple.

Comment: Expecting Attempt #4: `get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'wpcf-release-date', 1 )`

Comment: Ha, tried that first which is what caused me to query the DB.

Comment: Lol, the point is, it is really bad to query the DB while there's API to use. FYI, `get_post_meta` is cached and optimized, unserialized, and loads faster, unlike a direct SQL query, where you add more microseconds to your page load time, and extra server ressource usage..

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I tried that first and it did not work, so I looked for other solutions.

Comment: Sorry. Did you dump `$post_ID` if it has value? and look right at the PMA if it really has a meta in there? also turn on debugging mode, it might help.

Comment: You are accessing a $post variable in your functions php file, it cannot take dynamic ID because you are not in a loop, please describe what you are trying to achieve there. :)

Comment: @knif3r I've posted a solution to what I was trying to do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all of my attempts were viable (Thanks ehsaan for also confirming). The issue was that I was trying to get data from a field that was empty at the time of the function. (I was creating a new/updated post that hadn't updated the field yet).

**Solution (delay the hook):**

```
// Time out the custom field to update AFTER the post has been created/updated
function save_custom() {
    global $post;
    $post_ID = $post->ID;
    $result = get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'wpcf-release-date', 1 );

    // Add a new key "era"
    add_post_meta($post_ID, "era", $result, true);
    // If there is already a key "era", then update it
    if ( ! add_post_meta($post_ID, "era", $result, true) ) { 
       update_post_meta( $post_ID, "era", $result );
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom', 0);
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom', 10);
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom', 999);
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested your all attempts in a shortcode:

```
function add_test_shortcode() {
  global $wpdb;
  global $post;
  $post_ID = $post->ID;
  $wpdb->show_errors = true;
  $result = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT meta_value FROM '.$wpdb->postmeta.' WHERE meta_key="my_test" AND post_id=' . $post_ID);

  return $result;
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'add_test_shortcode' );
```

It worked perfectly for me, so there might something from your own code:

#### 1. Check for $post_ID

Make sure your `$post_ID` is valid, `get_the_ID()` might be a better replacement in so many cases than `global $post;`.

#### 2. Test your generated query

You can get your last executed query using `$wpdb->last_query`, execute it in phpMyAdmin or any other software and check that there is really a result.

#### 3. Look if there's any error

You can get the latest error statement using `$wpdb->last_error`.

My advice to you during WordPress development is that always keep `WP_DEBUG` on.